# Дано двумерный массив. Создайте программу, чтобы найти положительные элементы массива и заменить на число b

Tags: python

Задачка - мне дан двумерный массив. Нужно создать программу, чтобы найти положительные элементы массива и заменить на число `b` и найти индекс числа `b`.
Пытался писать так:

```py
 b=int(input('b ='))
 a=[[-12,6,9], [-49,25,5], [b,5,-27]]
 
 for i in a:
        for j in i:
            print(j,end=" ")
        print
 
        if j > 0:
               list.append(j)
               print (*[i for i in a if b in i])
        
 print(b)
```

Comment: Дубликат вопроса:[Дано двумерный массив.Создайте программу, чтобы найти число «B» внутри положительных элементов массива](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1210580/%d0%94%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-%d0%a1%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%83-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be-b-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5). Так же старый вопрос закрыт

Answer (score 0):

что мешает задачу решить в лоб как в математике 5 класса?

```
a = [[-12,6,9],[-49,25,5],[7,5,-27]]
b = 11

for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(a[i])):
        if a[i][j] > 0:
            a[i][j] = b

print(a)
```

или если хочется в 1 строчку, то можно так:

```
c = [[b if elem > 0 else elem for elem in line] for line in a]
```